# click event handler for span or td inside a table cell does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, click

I am populating a table when my page is loaded. My rows are created like below:

```
        $.each(datax, function() {
            $.each(this, function(kx , vx) {

                    tbl_row += '<td><p id="' +'^'+$key1+':'+$keyval1 +'^'+$key2+':'+$keyval2 +'^'+$key3+':'+$keyval3 +'^'+$key4+':'+$keyval4 +'^'+$key5+':'+$keyval5+ '$$'+kx+':'+vx+ '">'+vx+'</p></td>'; 
                    tbl_labels += "<th>"+kx+"</th>";
                })
                tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";   
                tbl_head  = "<tr>"+tbl_labels+"</tr>";                  
            })

            $("#table_results thead").html(tbl_head); 
            $("#table_results tbody").html(tbl_body); 
            $("#table_results").table("refresh");
```

It is working fine so far. The problem is, I want to handle click events for the table cells. I tried to put span and p inside the cells but the following handlers do not work

```
$("p").click(function (){
alert('handler for click p worked');
});

$("span").click(function (){
alert('handler for click span worked');
});
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When do you assign the click handlers? The way you're doing it, it must happen *after* the markup was inserted into the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$(document).on('click', 'p', function (){
    alert('handler for click p worked');
});

$(document).on('click', 'span', function (){
    alert('handler for click span worked');
});
```

It is using the [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which detects event on element dinamically created.

Comment: This is a thing of beauty. In all my years I've never seen that way of declaring events, and it works perfectly for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation here since the elements are added dynamically

```
$("#table_results").on('click', 'span', function(){
    alert('handler for click span worked');
})

$("#table_results").on('click', 'p', function(){
    alert('handler for click p worked');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check code below (which alerts cell text):

```
$("#tbl tbody").find("p").on("click",function (){
     alert($(this).text());
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kQpfE/

Answer (score -1):

You bind events on elements created after the DOM is ready. You need to bind them from a parent DOM element who isn't generated after DOM ready.

So you should do something like :

```
$("#table_results tbody").find('span').click(function (){
       alert('handler for click span worked');
});
```